# CSS Media queries - link to second stylesheet is not working

Tags: html, css

I am starting a new site and experimenting with responsive design.

Here is my html and css below, the tablet.css doesn't seem to be linking as it should show just a green version of the red main div. I have read some people suggest the having this both in the html and css files and some say you only need it in one? I have tried several different ways which none are working for me!

Any help would be appreciated! Cheers,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Homepage</title>


    <link href="resp_tablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" />
    <link href="resp_desktop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" />

    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="main">

      </div>

    </body>
    </html>

/*desktop version*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {



#main   {margin: 0 auto;
            width:1000px;
            height:382px;
            background-color:#F03;
}


}


/*tablet version*/

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {



#main   {margin: 0 auto;
            width:200px;
            height:182px;
            background-color:#0F0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to change link tags like this :

```
 <link href="resp_tablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)" />
 <link href="resp_desktop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)" />
```

Comment: Hi Dipali - thanks that works! - so I don't need to use the device part of max-device-width / min-device-width? Do you recommend using the @media in css along with the viewport so there is three components ? Thanks so much,

Comment: ya you don't need to use max/min-device-width. just use min/max-width. and you can use @viewport inside media queries for more precise optimization.